# CSS Submit Form doesn't look like it should

Tags: html, css

I have tried to change the submit button, but it isn't working perfectly.

in CSS  I have my button which works fine :

```
.button {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 4px 0 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/button_01.jpg) no-repeat;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And then I create the Submit type(obviously the code is the same):

```
input[type="submit"]{
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 4px 0 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/button_01.jpg) no-repeat;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

now if I create an html page :

```
<div class="button">  <a> Check Availability</a></div>

<input type="submit" value="Send"/>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
 <div class="button">  <a> whats up</a></div>
```

there is a lot of difference in appeareance.  all the buttons must seems like the first button and the fourth.   I don't understand why the submit button has this borders.
Here is the screenshot:
        [Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/ucxpae52p/)

```
    Any ideas guys how can i fix it ?
```

Comment: If you just want to remove the borders then you can simply add `border:0;`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are styling two completely different elements which is why they look different. The `input` elements have default styles that the `div` and `a` elements do not have.

You need to inspect the elements and see which default styles need to be overwritten. Based off of your screenshot, I'd guess that something like this might work for the borders:

```
input[type="submit"]{
    ...
    border:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rD2Jz/

Answer (score 1):

When you specify an element, like you're styling for input type = submit, it goes over the rules of the class, so you will have to standardize all their input type = submit, and then stylize each class with additional rules.

In your case, you can simply put a border: 0 none in the style of input type = submit, that the border will disappear for all submit.

Here is a the code I described a little more optimized in link http://zip.net/bhmYLW

Avoid having to use style as deep as input [type = "submit"] without proper inheritance, this can cause a lot of problems.

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment Dryden's answer so I'll just add this:

The elements you are styling might already be having some style added to them, which is mixing things up. Make sure your css file is the last one to be called on the page, so that the changes it makes are the ones that count.

Good luck!

Comment: I guess there were default styles that needed to be overwritten.. Thank you .